# Data VAlidation - Text Length & Character Type

Tags: excel

I would like to add some data validation on a cell in the Excel 10. I would like to force the user to enter a string that is 9-char long, with the first 8 char as digits, and the last char an Upper letter.

Thanking u in advance

Comment: this custom formula will satisfy the first two requirements: `=AND(LEN(A1)=9,ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,8)+0))` ... AFAIK, you'll need VBA to satisfy the last. Or you could just ignore the last and use the `UPPER` formula `=Left(A1,9) & Upper(Right(A1,1))` to convert the last value to uppercase always before using the cell value in another place.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this formula could help:

```
=and(isnumber(left(A1,8)+0),len(A1)=9,code(right(A1))>=65,code(right(A1))<=90)
```

- `isnumber(left(A1,8)+0)` = with the first 8 char as digits
- `len(A1)=9` =  9-char long
- `code(right(A1))>=65,code(right(A1))<=90` = char between "A" and "Z"

Comment: Hi Max, at first i would like to thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you! Was it helpful, or you have some difficulties?

Comment: Hi Max. Well i do have an ' issue' but I believe that it wont affect my sheet... When i save the formula as data validation i get a msj like ' the formula evaluates to an error '. If I ignore the mjs the formula works, so that's why i did not disturb you further:-)... Thanks Max, much appreciated