# data validation with numbers + text

Tags: excel, validation

Trying to write a custom data validation formula that would only allow values in the following format: 2-digit year (this can be just 2 numbers), dash ("-"), then a 1 or 2 letter character(s) (would prefer upper case, but would settle for lower case), another dash ("-"), and then a 5-digit number.  So the final value looks like: 17-FL-12345   ...or 16-G-00008...

I actually have a but more, but if I could get the above working, that would be terrific. I don't know if there's a way, but it would be great if additionally I could use custom formatting to get the dashes to appear when they are not entered, i.e., user enters "17FL12345" and it gets automatically formatted to "17-FL-12345". Finally, again, this isn't a deal breaker either, but it would also be great if the last 5 digits would add any leading zero's, i.e., the user enters 17-G-8 (or just 17G8) and it gets formatted to 17-G-00008.

Can't use VBA unfortunately. Some potential solutions to similar questions I've viewed include:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/615799-data-validation-mixed-numeric-text-formula-only.html

[Data VAlidation - Text Length & Character Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138296/data-validation-text-length-character-type)

[Excel : Data Validation, how to force the user to enter a string that is 2 char long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503830/excel-data-validation-how-to-force-the-user-to-enter-a-string-that-is-2-char)

Comment: To do the formatting you will need vba.  Also allowing the user to enter it without dashes would nullify the data validation.  If vba is off the table you will only be able to do the first, and that is if the formula can be done with less than 255 characters, which may be pushing it.  So the entry would require the dashes and the full numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? As @ScottCraner writes, you cannot do the formatting without VBA.  So show us the formula you have tried and where you have run into problems.  You'll need an `IF` to decide on checking for one letter or two; the rest should be fairly straightforward (just tedious to write out).

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the info... would be acceptable to just get the first part... requiring the user to use dashes and the full number is not a huge deal

Comment: As @RonRosenfeld it is fairly tedious as one would need to parse the string and check each part.  What have you tried?  We can give pointers as to why your formula is failing.  But usually we do not write for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))),MID(A1,3,1)="-",OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,4,1),$C$1)),AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,4,1),$C$1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,5,1),$C$1)))),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-5,1)="-",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,5))),OR(LEN(A1)=11,LEN(A1)=10),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))=2,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",""))=0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=0)
```

Assuming, you want to validate A1. I inserted the letters in C1. 
[image]

Edit:

I edited the original function, to be more secure and left out the `Isnumber` part and rather went digit by digit.
If you want exceed the 255 limit, you have to slice the function up.
I created 5 functions.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(A1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,2,1),$C$2)))

=MID(A1,3,1)="-"

=IF(LEN(A1)=10,AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,4,1),$C$1)),MID(A1,5,1)="-"),IF(LEN(A1)=11,AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,4,1),$C$1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,5,1),$C$1)))))

=IF(LEN(A1)=10,MID(A1,5,1)="-",IF(LEN(A1)=11,MID(A1,6,1)="-"))

=IF(LEN(A1)=10,AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,6,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,7,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,8,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,9,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,10,1),$C$2))),IF(LEN(A1)=11,AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,7,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,8,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,9,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,10,1),$C$2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,11,1),$C$2)))))
```

Set up data validation as on the picture:

[image]

Comment: I think I have it correct now:  Your formula seems to return `TRUE` for `12-FG--1234`.  You probably need to go digit by digit as leading spaces, `-` and `+` will test positive on isnumeric.  Also, suggest you change C1 to the absolute address.

Comment: @Vinnie this is awesome! THANKS! I need to play with it a bit to match my sheet, but it evaluates to true when I put in as a stand alone formula. I was about to respond to Ron Rosenfeld that I was playing with =AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT...MID(ISTEXT(...)...ISNUMBER(RIGHT(...)  - but needed to add the dashes and OR statement. At least I was on the right track.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for checking. I added criteria that we need exactly 2 `-` and no`+`.

Comment: Any ideas on getting around the 255 validation formula limit? This is being used in an expanding table, so the "A1" will have to reference the current cell's row.

Comment: @Vinnie thanks... I just created a hidden helper column at end of my table with your first formula, replacing A1 with [@[#Ref]]; then made a named range =Table1[@[Helper Column]], then had the validation = the named range. It all works! Thanks again.

Comment: @Vinnie or anyone else... do you happen to be familiar with Excel Online (SharePoint 2013) and know why this is working on my desktop Excel version (2013) but not Excel online (edit in Browser mode)? All the other data validations work online, but this process of the validation formula referring back to the helper column(s) which refer to the input cell does not validate at all.

Comment: @Mark I couldn't find anything about this, but I have the assumption that the online version doesn't support this option.